# Simple Search returning no results

Tags: search, simple-search

I'm having an issue with a simple search returning no results for a channel. All the fields in the channel are plain text fields, and all are set to be searchable. All entries in the channel have a status of "open".

I can display the contents of this channel's entries just fine, but search is consistently sending me to the no results page. My search form code is:

```
{exp:search:simple_form form_id="peopleSearchForm" no_result_page="search/no-results" result_page="search/index" channel="employee_list" search_in="everywhere" status="open" where="all" show_expired="yes" show_future_entries="yes"}
<input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords">
<input type="image" src="/images/interface/btn_search.png" name="people-submit" id="people-submit" alt="Search People">
 {/exp:search:simple_form}
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated. I'm completely stumped.

(Site is using EE 2.8.1)

Comment: Your results page has the search results tags right?

Comment: Also what happens when you replace that input image type with a regular submit button?

Comment: Hi -- Yes, I tried with a regular submit button, same outcome. My results page contains the following to display results: `{exp:search:search_results}
<div class="results">
<strong>{first_name} {last_name}</strong><br />
{job_title}<br />
{business_unit}<br />
{job_location}<br />
{if work_phone}Tel {work_phone}<br />{/if}
{if cell_phone}{cell_phone}<br />{/if}
<a href="mailto:{work_email}">{work_email}</a>
</div>
{/exp:search:search_results}`